# What's the purpose of "const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;" as in react QUICK START/Conditional Rendering doc?

Tags: reactjs

In the react [Conditional Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) doc:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

What's the purpose of using `const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;` and `isLoggedIn` instead of using `props.isLoggedIn` directly?
And why const?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to answer here:

### Why not just use `props.isLoggedIn` directly?

Totally valid question. And they could've done that:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  if (props.isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

There really is no reason to assign it to a variable, unless they were going to reference it several times. In that case, it would be to save typing:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const name = props.name;

  return <div>
    <SomeComponent name={name} />
    <AnotherComponent name={name} />
    {/* 10 more components using name */}
  </div>
}
```

Another shorthand way of doing this would be:

```
function Greeting({ isLoggedIn }) {
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

If you're not familiar with that format, it's called [destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html) and is a feature of JavaScript ES6/ES2015.

How I would've done it:

```
function Greeting({ isLoggedIn }) {
  return isLoggedIn ? <UserGreeting /> : <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

### Why `const`?

I *always* use `const`, period, unless I know it's a variable I'll want to modify later, in which case I use `let`. Using `const` simply prevents you from making mistakes by overwriting an important variable.

Note that variables declared with `const` can't be changed, but if it's an object, properties can be added/modified. For instance:

```
const a = 'hello';
const b = ['pumpkin'];
const c = { name: 'Bob' };

a = 'bye'; // this will throw an error
b.push('pie'); // this is valid
c.age = 38; // so is this
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% but from the looks of it I would guess it is to ensure that the value of `isLoggedIn` is not altered when this function is running. As seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) `const` value cannot be changed through re-assignment (not to be confused with immutable values) so you can make sure the value will not change from under you.

Answer (score 1):

It would really work either way. I think they encourage using `const` because they recommend [immutability](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#using-immutable-data-structures) in general. `const` ensures that you don't later assign a new value to that variable within that scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the documentation, in the constructor,  `this.state = {isLoggedIn: false}`

then later they set `const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;`

Therefore, `const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn` is the same as

`const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn` which by default is set to false when the component is rendered.

Now if `isLoggedIn` is true, the  `<UserGreeting />` component is rendered otherwise, the
`<GuestGreeting />`     component is rendered.

Here, you CANNOT use:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  if (props.isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```

simply because you have to set `const isLoggedIn3 = props.isLoggedIn2;` so you can use state and at the same time you have to use props to import properties that were initiated in the constructor. Therefore, you have to use:

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn3 = props.isLoggedIn2;
  if (isLoggedIn3) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}
```